# Core Video examples for iOS

Tags: video, ios4, core-video

Does anyone know of any tutorials and examples for using Core Video **except** for the [Core Video Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreVideo/CVProg_Intro/CVProg_Intro.html)?

Comment: I would like to know this also. I am having a heck of a time finding any information on core video

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to the CocoaIsMyGirlfriend post: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/09/10/core-animation-tutorial-rendering-quicktime-movies-in-a-caopengllayer/

If you use CoreVideo in an intermediate/advanced way, it will be cool to post a tutorial ;)